# Does making a field `volatile` prevent all memory visibility issues in a concurrent situation?

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-model

Does making a class field `volatile` prevent *all* memory visibility issues with it in a concurrent situation ? Is it possible that for below class , a thread that gets a reference of a `Test` object sees `x` as 0 first ( the default value of `int` ) and then 10 ? I am thinking this to be possible *if and only if* the Constructor of `Test` gives away `this` reference without completing ( improper publishing ) . Can someone validate/correct me ?

```
class Test {
    volatile int x = 10;            
}
```

Second question: what if it was `final int x=10;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually not guaranteed to see x = 10 according to the JMM.

For example if you have

```
Test test =  null;

Thread 1 -> test = new Test();
Thread 2 -> test.x  == // even though test != null, x can be seen as 0 if the
                       // write of x hasn't yet occur
```

Now if you had

```
class Test{
  int y = 3;
  volatile x = 10;
}
```

If thread-2 reads x == 10 thread-2 is guaranteed to read y == 3

To answer your second question.

Having a final field will issue a storestore after the constructor and before publishing so having the field final will actually ensure you see x = 10.

Edit: As yshavit  noted. You lose the happens-before relationship I mention in my first example with final fields, that is as yshavit put it if thread-2 reads x == 10 it may not read y == 3 where x is a final field.

Comment: Referring to your first code snippet , if the reference `test` is declared `final` , then can it be guarenteed that Thread 2 sees `test.x` as 10 , provided `test != null` is true  ?

Comment: But just to clarify, if `x` is final then you lose the guarantee that if thread-2 reads `x == 10` it must also read `y == 3`.

Comment: @Bhaskar Yes, unless `this` is leaked from the constructor in `Test`. If you leak `this`, all bets are off.

Comment: @JohnVint Just to elaborate slightly for clarity, you only lose the happens-before guarantee of volatile with final if you leak `this` in the constructor.  If you do not leak the object then there are additional guarantees provided by final as explained [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/).

Comment: @increment1 Just to elaborate on the elaboration ( :) ), the JMM guarantees of `final` are pretty limited -- just the `final` field itself, and any fields referenced through it, are guaranteed to be seen in the state they were in when the constructor finished (unless they're updated). But there is no HB relationship between any `final` field and any other field in the object.

Answer (score 3):

Even in a single threaded implementation, you are not guaranteed to see x = 10 if you leak *this* in the constructor.  So the issue you can experience here is not directly a concurrency issue, but an order of execution issue (depending on when you leak *this*).  E.g. if you leak *this* in a parent constructor for instace:

```
public class TestParent
{
  public TestParent()
  {
    if (this instanceof TestChild)
    {
      TestChild child = (TestChild) this;
      System.out.println(child.field);  // will print 0 when TestChild is instantiated.
    }
  }
}


public class TestChild extends TestParent
{
  volatile int field = 10;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  TestChild child = new TestChild();
  System.out.println(child.field);

  // The above results in 0 (from TestParent constructor) then 10 being printed.
}
```

Final fields, on the other hand, are guaranteed to have the assigned initial value so long as that assignment is done on the declaring line (if you make the field final but initialize it in the constructor then you can still leak *this* before and show the uninitialized value.

Comment: That's when _instance initialization blocks_ come handy, you can do funky multi-line assigments/computations before any constructor gets called :)